# how to change the reference of an object through the object itself

Tags: java, oop

i'm trying to implement a data structure using java (a linke list) which requires me to change the references of its objects using a methode inside the objects them self whenever i add or delete an element from this DS
how can i change it ??

what i tried was using "this"

```
public class Liste {
private Element info;
private Liste suiv ;


public void add(Liste p , Element e) {
    Liste nouv , pt ;
    nouv = new Liste();
    nouv.info=e;
    nouv.suiv=p;
    if(p==this) {
//i tried to change what's indside this 
//but didn't even pass the compolation
this=nouv;}
        else{...}
 
}
 


}
```

Comment: That isn't going to work. Java in general doesn't use references as other programming languages and an Objects can't suddenly decide it is another object.

Comment: and this compiles?????

Comment: I would recommend describing why you think you need to do this, so that others might point out how this can be achieved with a different method. But as already said what you are asking is impossible in java.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a List class will have a helper class called a "Node" that you allocated to update the pointers.  Please check with your instructor, I think you missed some of the lecture.

(Not tested:)

```
public class Liste {
  private static class Node { Element info; Node next; }
  private Node head;
  private Node tail;

  public void add(Element e) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.info = e;
    if( tail != null ) tail.next = node;
    if( head == null ) head = node;
    tail = node;     
  }
}
```